# jQuery looping array to display each element at new line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

get all selected checkbox value and display them
wanted to separate each element in the array into new line

```js
$('#generate').on('click', function() {
      var array = [];
      $("input:checked").each(function() {
        array.push($(this).val());
      });
    
      $("#selectedSubject").text(array+'<br>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please add relevant html

Comment: `array.push($(this).val() + '<br>');` `$("#selectedSubject").text(array.join()); `

Comment: Or even simpler `("#selectedSubject").text(array.join('<br>'));`

Comment: Consider using [map](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

Answer (score 1):

ok so i fixed it myself
on last line i kept using .text instead of .html thats what made me failed oof

```
$('#generate').on('click', function() {
  var array = [];
  $("input:checked").each(function() {
    array.push($(this).val());
  });
  let text = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  text += array[i] + "<br>";
  }
  $("#selectedSubject").html(text);
```

Answer (score 0):

use each agian to iterate over the new array

ie:

```
$.each(array, function( index, value ) {
 $("#selectedSubject").append( value ); 
});
```

Comment: @GrafiCode Baby steps - if you're using `each` to read the values, then makes sense to use `each` to output them again.  No `each` is needed for the original question (including the one in the question).   Why generate an array at all?  But there it is in the question.